# php wordpress password change - logging me out!

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a simple wordpress password change script of my own (well, based on a plugin really) - the password is successfully changed - but it logs me out after the change completes! Below is the code used. Can anyone see where I'm being logged out and how to prevent it? Thanks!

```
$update = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->users} SET `user_pass` = %s WHERE `ID` = %d",array(wp_hash_password($_POST['admin_pass1']),$user_ID)));

if(!is_wp_error($update))
{
    wp_cache_delete($user_ID,'users');
    wp_cache_delete($user->user_login,'userlogins');
    wp_logout();
    if (wp_signon(array('user_login'=>$user->user_login,'user_password'=>$_POST['admin_pass1']),false)):
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
    endif;
    ob_start();
}
```

Comment: I would assume that `wp_logout();` has something to do with it lol

Comment: of course, but the signon function after it should bring me straight back to my dashboard...this is from the plugin which worked fine on its own...

Comment: the fact is even with that block removed - wordpress still seems to logs me out which personally i find bizarre....

Comment: @madmartigan indeed. "Every time I hit my hand with a hammer, a hammer seems to hit my hand. why is that?"

Answer (score 4):

After resetting password you have to set/reset cookies (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie)
like this

```
$update = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$wpdb->users} SET `user_pass` = %s WHERE `ID` = %d",array(wp_hash_password($_POST['admin_pass1']),$user_ID)));

if(!is_wp_error($update))
{
    wp_cache_delete($user_ID,'users');
    wp_cache_delete($user->user_login,'userlogins');
    wp_logout();
    if (wp_signon(array('user_login'=>$user->user_login,'user_password'=>$_POST['admin_pass1']),false)):
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
    endif;
    ob_start();
}else{
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $current_user_id, true);
}
```

To reset the password you'd better use wordpress functions like wp_check_password and wp_set_password because of integration with other applications/plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Was linked here from another post, and wanted to give an updated solution to this problem, as some of these solutions (especially modifying wpdb->query directly) aren't best practice anymore.

Update the user's password using wp_set_password(), and then log the user back in, using wp_signon().

wp_signon will create the authentication cookie for you, as other users have suggested, but in a much more streamlined way.

```
function create_new_password_for_user($new_password){
    //Get the current user's details, while they're still signed in, in this scope.
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
     $users_login = $current_user->user_email;

    //set their new password (this will trigger the logout)
    wp_set_password($new_password, $current_user_id);

    //setup the data to be passed on to wp_signon
    $user_data = array(
            'user_login'     => $users_login,
            'user_password'    => $new_password,
            'remember'        => false
        );

    // Sign them back in.
    $result = wp_signon( $user_data );

    if(is_wp_error($result)){
      //do something with an error, if there is one.
    }else{
      //do something with the successful change. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this:

```
if(!is_wp_error($update))
{
    wp_cache_delete($user_ID,'users');
    wp_cache_delete($user->user_login,'userlogins');
    wp_logout();
    if (wp_signon(array('user_login'=>$user->user_login,'user_password'=>$_POST['admin_pass1']),false)):
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
    endif;
    ob_start();
}
```

means that if there are no errors the following functions will be executed. One of this functions is `wp_logout()` which will be always called if the conditional block is executed.

If it's not what you want, then you want to consider replacing:

```
if(!is_wp_error($update))
```

with:

```
if(is_wp_error($update))
```

Comment: I don't even use WP and `wp_logout()` seemed obvious. To me I saw `if no error updating then do stuff including wp_logout()`. In fact, none of the stuff in that block looks like it necessary, but as I said, I don't use WP

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it won't log you out after password change and it works with Ajax too. Also, no need to reset cookies/session after it.

```
$userdata['ID'] = 1; //user ID
$userdata['user_pass'] = 'new_password';
wp_update_user( $userdata ); // this will handle encryption and everything
```

Cheers

Comment: be careful, this would trigger a 'change password email' to be sent out, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: @WaltyYeung Sure, will take care of this. But, I thought this would be useful in case if you're a developer and you forget your admin password and your emails are not working on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the code is run before the end of HTTP headers and the beginning of regular page content. You may not get any warning if you inadvertently wait too long in the page generation process. It'll all just fail silently and you'll be logged out mysteriously (even though `wp_signon()` returns a valid `WP_User` object).

Answer (score 0):

if you still look for an answer on this topic:, i found a solution!

in short, after you update the password, clear the data and logout 
( as you did)

```
wp_cache_delete($user_ID,'users');
wp_cache_delete($user->user_login,'userlogins');
wp_logout();
```

user is logged out now

then

do a 'redirect' to a new page to auto-login again 
Catch the call to this page via a `add_action( 'wp', 'auto_login' );` 
(we must do this, before anything is send via 'headers')

the auto_login function then can handle your request to auto login the given user.(via $_GET parameters)

So when i redirect to the new page i pass on two parameters
user_id (the user to login)
a secret key (for security)

```
$key =  password_hash('[some secret ]' . $user_id, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $to['fl_autologin'] ) . "/?p=" . urlencode( $key ) . "&z=" . $user_id );
        exit;
```

then in the auto_login function i look for those two parameters
decrypt the secret key to check if this is oke

```
            if ( $_GET['z'] && password_verify( '[some secret]' . $_GET['z'], urldecode( $_GET['p'] ) )) {
```

if so, 
then login the given user

```
$user    = get_user_by( 'id', $_GET['z'] );
            $user_id = $user->ID;
wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

            do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
```

do some more security checks on this, 
like user_id must be valid etc
if all oke,
then you can redirect him to a home_page again

hope this helps your issue