# Make a wordpress change password page? on a template not on admin

Tags: wordpress

how do i make a wordpress change password page? im pretty sure its possible with `wp_set_password`, but not sure how best to do it.

basically i need to replicate the change password form in the wp admin in a page, its a custom "my account" type of page.

Can anybody give some pointers?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35336444/4819200 solution

Answer (score 4):

The best way to learn how this is done is to download and study the code in a plugin like this: [change password and email](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/change-password-e-mail/) or [theme my login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) to learn what Wordpress functions are used and basically write your own thing. It might even be worth using and or modifying those plugins to your liking.