# Change User Password ! Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, passwords, frontend

I wrote a wordpress template page to allow my users to change their password on FrontEnd.

On the form I check the current password and ask for the new password and a confirmation.
Everything works fine for several changing passwords.

But when the new password is equal to a previous old password, it becomes impossible for the user to connect. I have to reset the password on the admin to restore access.

Anyone know why ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35336444/4819200 solution

Answer (score 0):

Just validate they are not the same with an if statement. If the current password = new password then don't update the DB and return a message informing the user that they can't use the same password!

Answer (score 0):

Please enter the username and password which is enter at that time.Here is the variable which you need to provide the value.
1: $username
2: $pass

```
 $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

if ( $user && wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass , $user->ID  ) )
{
message :Please use the another password
}
```